# Limit application invites - Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a code that auto invites users to an event that I create upon their acceptance of the application, but it auto invites all their friends, is there a possible way to limit the amount of friends it invites, and instead of inviting them every time they view the app, limit it to just the initial acceptance of the application?

Code:

```
$bsize = 400;

require_once('settings.php');

$_SESSION['init'] = true;
$current_date=date('m/d/Y');



 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $settings['appid'],
      'secret' => $settings['secret'],
      'cookie' => true,
    ));

//Facebook Authentication part
$session = $facebook->getSession();
$appurl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
        'canvas'    => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
                'uid' => $uid,
        'req_perms' => 'create_event,rsvp_event'
        )
);

$fbme = null;

if (!$session) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$appurl';</script>";
    exit;
} else {
    try {
        $uid      =   $facebook->getUser();
        $fbme     =   $facebook->api('/me?fields=id');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$appurl';</script>";
        exit;
    }
}



$rsvpResult = $facebook->api('/'.$eventid.'/attending','POST', array() );


$friendIDs = array();
try { 
    $result = $facebook->api('/me/friends?fields=id');
    foreach ($result['data'] as $friend) {
        $friendIDs[] = $friend['id'];
    }
} catch(Exception $o) {
    echo $o."ERROR: Friends do not allow invitations!";
}

$eid = "$eventid";

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(false);
$eventInviteParam = array(
    'method' => 'events.invite',
    'eid' => $eid,
    'personal_message'=> 'Check this out',
    'access_token' => $session['access_token']
);
if( count($friendIDs) > 0 ){
    $i =0;
    $friendIDPartialList = array_chunk($friendIDs, $bsize);
//  echo "list count :".count($friendIDPartialList);
    foreach($friendIDPartialList as $flist){
        $eventInviteParam['uids'] = $flist;
        try {
            $result = $facebook->api($eventInviteParam);
        }  catch(Exception $o) { echo $o; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can autoinvite the user's friends without violating Facebook's policy:
http://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Let the user actively issue invitations through a clearly labled button, and you'll be OK.